# Is it safe to use sync.Pool reference as context value?

Tags: http, go, synchronization

I have struct that uses `sync.Pool`.

Is it safe to use this reference as context value?

```
type User struct {
    ID string
}

var userPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return &User{}
    },
}

func getUser() *User {
    return userPool.Get().(*User)
}

func recycleUser(user *User) {
    userPool.Put(user)
}
```

The user struct is retrieved from pool in middleware.

```
func middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // get user from pool
        user := getUser()
        // user must be recycled 
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", user)
    }
}
```

And recycled in handler.

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := r.Context().Value("user").(*User)

    // TODO: do something with user

    // put user struct back into pool
    recycleUser(user)
}
```

Edit:

My question is more about how context deals with pointer to my object. Does it make a copy? Is it safe to use non-primitive object with context?

Answer (score 0):

There are three points to make:

## Usage of sync.Pool

Your usage of pool is as intended. From [golang Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool)

> A Pool is safe for use by multiple goroutines simultaneously.

## Retrieving users

`getUser` uses `func (p *Pool) Get() interface{}` which removes the returned item from the pool, afterwards you can do whatever you please 
with that value. In your case, thats a `*User`. Whether the associated
ressource is safe to use, well, depends on your usage of those values in the rest of the program.

## Recycling users

Calling `recycleUser` within the hander is potentially dangerous, depending on your environment.

What could possibly go wrong?

After `recycleUser` returned your `*User` back to the pool, it could be retrieved and used by a different goroutine immediately. But at the same time, `*User` is still stored in the context assiociated with the request. So it depends if any of the functions of your middleware use the `*User` from the context, too and wether they store the `*User` value. Or if you later add some code after the `recycleUser`, which uses the `*User` value. After the `recycleUser` call, all those usages probably operate on the wrong user, which is already used by some different request.

## How to solve those issues

1. coding convention

   - if you retrieve the user in middleware functions, don't store it
   - if you retrieve the user in middleware functions, don't use it after the call to the next handler in the chain.
   - don't call `recycleUser` in middleware functions
   - retrieve the user in the leaf handler (last handler in the chain, doesn't calls any further handlers propagating the context and thus the `*User`) and use `defer recycleUser(user)` to put back the `*User` in the pool and make it impossible that later added code uses `*User` after the call to `recycleUser(user)`.
   - in the leaf handler, don't use `*User` in code which is called by some `defer` usage in the leaf handler, other than `recycleUser`.
2. ensuring the coding convention by technical means. My only idea here would be to place the `*User` inside some struct and only use that struct for one request and mark it as empty, once `*User` is put back into the pool. Make all access methods of that struct check for emptyness and panic/log/whatever, if an empty struct is accessed. Place a pointer to that struct in the context. But that is probably pointless, as you now allocate that struct for each request, instead of a `User`, which probably was, what you tried to avoid.

## A minor remark

You probably meant your middleware function to read like:

```
func middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // get user from pool
        user := getUser()
        // user must be recycled 
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", user)
        // probably do something more
        next(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    }
}
```